# PyQt Confusion with Inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt, qtgui

I try to organize my code and therefore put some stuff into modules.
I would like several variables,, such as a `statusBar()`, in the main code section to be altered by imported modules.
I made a quick minimal working example to show what I mean:

Here is my main.py:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import module
import sys

class ApplicationWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Main window initalized")
        module.Test()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ApplicationWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is module.py:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
class Test(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        print 'hello'
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Test module called", 6000)
```

The code prints `"hello"` and does not throw me any error, so I assume the module is successfully imported and Test is initialized, but it does not alter the `statusBar()` in my ApplicationWindow somehow. How can I achieve that? It's probably a silly mistake, so sorry in advance for bothering you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Test` class have to reference to the `ApplicationWindow` class. 
`self.statusBar().showMessage("Test module called", 6000)` will set a message on the status bar for the window of `Test` (A window that is lost to the void since it is never made visible or assigned to any variable)

Passing an instance of `ApplicationWindow` to `Test` would be one way to do what you want. `Test` also does not need to inherit from `QtGui.QMainWindow` for this.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import module
import sys

class ApplicationWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Main window initalized", 6000)
        module.Test(self)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ApplicationWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()  



# module.py 

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        print 'hello'
        parent.statusBar().showMessage("Test module called", 6000)
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I messed up the inheritance. For me the code is only working when `object` is written in lower case letters.

Comment: `Object` was a typo, should be `object`. Thanks